# Writing a minitest spec model test for case statement setting attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, minitest

I'm writing a model test in minitest-spec for the following model method:

```
  def self.attributes_for_state(state)
    case state
    when :closed
      attributes = {
        active: false,
        selected: false,
        staged: false,
      }
    when :selected
      attributes = {
        active: true,
        selected: true,
        selected_at: Time.zone.now,
        staged: false,
        staged_at: nil,
      }
  else
      raise "Invalid state choice, no attributes defined for #{state}"
    end
  end
```

I wrote an earlier test where an if statement of attributes determined the state, but this one is flipped - state determines attributes instead. How do I set up a case statement for an attribute list? I have an idea (below), but it's nebulous:

Assume I'm sticking with the structure of the other tests in my spec file (`describe`/`it`)

```
describe "#attributes_for_state" do
  it "returns closed attributes when state is :closed" do
     # attributes_for_state(state)
    create ps = :product_selection, :closed #Factory/trait not registered
    assert_equal(ps.attributes_for_state(:closed), {active: false, selected: false, staged: false, staging: false, destaging: false,})
end

    end
    it "should have :selected attributes" do

    end
    it "should have :staged attributes" do

    end        
  end
```

Factory, for reference:

```
factory :product_selection do
  account {|ps| ps.association(:account) }
  user {|ps| ps.association(:user) }

 active { true }
 selected { false }
 staging { false }
 staged { false }
 staged_at { nil }    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually arrange the spec like this:

```
describe 'method name' do
  subject { ... }

  context 'when some condition' do
    //define vars with 'let'

    //setup the mocks in a 'before' hook (only before each)

    it 'does something' do
      // Just check that the subject is what you expect
    end
  end
end
```

Also, if I don't really really need it, I don't create real objects, and just use `double`.

So one way you could do it is like this:

```
describe "#attributes_for_state" do
  subject { described_class.attributes_for_state(state) }

  context 'when closed' do
    let(:state) { :closed }
    let(:expected_attr) do
      {
        active: false,
        selected: false,
        staged: false,
      }
    end
    it { should eq expected_attr }
  end

  context 'when selected' do
    let(:time_zone) { double(now: time) }
    let(:time) { 'some_time' }
    let(:state) { :selected }
    let(:expected_attr) do
      {
        active: true,
        selected: true,
        selected_at: time,
        staged: false,
        staged_at: nil,
      }
    end

    before do
      allow(Time).to receive(:zone).and_return(time_zone)
    end

    it { should eq expected_attr }
  end
end
```

Basically, the upper describe should be with the method name, and the context is to separate your test into different cases, a good thumb rule, is to always start your context with words like 'when' and 'with'...

Use subject to indicate what you are testing, in this case it is the result of the method, and each context define its state and the expected attributes.

You can check also undefined state:

```
context 'when not defined' do
  let(:state) { "some_not_defined_state" }

  it 'raises runtime error' do
    expect { subject }.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
  end
end
```

When checking for raising error it is important to be specific what type of error you are expecting...

edit:
When you arrange the spec like this, the bonus is that when you run it with `guard`, you get some of a documentation for you code:

[image]